# Linq group by using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, system.reflection

I have data table "Car" which have 3 cols (owner, carType, colour). My question is how can i make the grouping portion more dynamic by using reflection. my idea is add the grouping col in to array, then use the reflection on the query grouping part. however i was struck at the reflection..

```
var gcols = new string[] { "owner", "carType" };                         
var reseult = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => new
                     {
                         carType = x.Field<string>("carType"),
                         colour = x.Field<string>("colour")
                     })
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                         CarType = x.Key.carType,
                         Colour = x.Key.colour,
                         count = x.Count()
                     })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.CarType).ToList();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: Similar to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/39028ad2-452e-409f-bc9e-d1b263e921f6/) ?

Comment: what i wanna to do is to have dynamic grouping based on the columns in the gcols array instead of hard code the grouping col in the query

Comment: Thanks I4V - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx did the job. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you added this extension method to object:

```
    public static T Field<T>(this object source, string FieldName)
    {
        var type = source.GetType();
        var field = type.GetField(FieldName);
        return (T)field.GetValue(source);
    }
```

You'd be able to use the syntax you've posted in your code.

I've not added any safety checking here so it'll need cleaning up, but it'll get you going. Ideally you'd want to check that the type of `field` is the same as `T` and a few other checks.

Comment: can u show how to apply it to my code ? what should i pass in in source? datatable ?

Comment: It's an extension method - it adds a 'Field' method to all objects, so you just put it anywhere and it should work with the exact code you posted above.

Comment: Then the object is null. How are you trying to use it?